# File Upload Redirect with Error Not Display

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm not sure what is the cause of my file upload. It's failing and redirecting back, but **not with error**.

---

## Controller

```
public function updateLogo()
{

    $inputs = Input::all();
    $logo_path = Input::only('logo_path');
    $cpe_mac = $inputs['cpe_mac'];
    $rule =  ['logo_path' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'];

    $validator = Validator::make($logo_path, $rule );

    if ( $validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to($cpe_mac.'/view-profile/')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    } else {

    ..... 

    }
```

---

## View

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/'.$cpe_mac.'/view-profile/logo/update', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' =>'form','id' => 'editLogo','file'=>true)) !!}

  <input name="logo_path" type="file" required> <br><br>

   <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr5" type="file"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Update Logo</button>

{!! Form::hidden('cpe_mac', $cpe_mac)!!}
{{ csrf_field() }}
{!! Form::close();!!}
```

---

Did I forget something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your validation slightly in order to get this to work to follow up on @marmorunl answer.

```
public function updateLogo()
{
    $input = [
        'logo_path' => Input::file('logo_path')
    ];

    $rules = [
        'logo_path' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|required'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
         return Redirect::to($cpe_mac.'/view-profile/')->withErrors($validator)->withInput()
    } else {
        // else
    }
};
```

See [Laravel: Validate an uploaded file is an image](http://dor.ky/laravel-validate-an-uploaded-file-is-an-image/) for additional information. This suggests using `image` as the validation rule which would also include git and svg. So I've left it as the mime type one you where using in case you don't want this.

Answer (score 3):

A file (really uploaded file, so not just a string) can be called with `Input::file()`; It isn't included in the standard `Input::all()`.